# По трое детей: как быть с падежом?

Tags: синтаксис

https://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&num=10

Словосочетание **"по трое детей"**. Имеют (по сколько?) по трое детей. Винительный количественный. В позиции такого винительного счётный оборот со стержневым собирательным числительным.

Дети (мн. от ребёнок) - одушевлённое сущ, следовательно в счётном обороте надо говорить: нет (кого?) троих детей (род. п.) и винить (кого?) троих детей (вин. п.) Формы род. и вин. идентичны.

Но если такой винительный употребляется с предлогом по (имеющим распределительное значение), то уже нельзя сказать ***"имеют по троих детей"***, "соблюдая" одушевлённость.

Тут утвердилась форма: имеют (по сколько?) "по трое детей", как если бы "дети" было неодушевлённым. То есть тут числительное управляет родительным "детей" не только в своём именительном, но и в своём винительном. То есть, выходит, в сочетаниях с **"по"** дети становится неодушевлённым сущ. и управляется числительным, когда числительное в именительном и винительном стоит?

Ср.: (что?) пятьсот рублей (им. п.), скинемся (по сколько?) по пятьсот рублей. Идентичность им. и вин. п. при неодушевлённом управляемом "рубль".

Answer (score 1):

Предлог "по" при существительном обычно управляет **дательным** падежом, что верно и для *сочетания числительного с существительным*: скучать **по троим детям**, **по трём детям**. С числительным же этот предлог способен образовывать *наречное сочетание* **по трое** http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2883#pp2883 (как именно построены, по скольку в ряд или по скольку приходится на человека? - вопрос сфокусирован на *числительном*), в котором числительное может находиться либо в *именительном*, либо в *винительном* падеже, которые не различаются по форме числительного. Поэтому при наличии предлога "по" и падеже всего сочетания, отличном от **дательного** (т.е. именительный, либо винительный), падежом существительного может управлять только числительное (но не предлог "по"), а одушевлённость роли не играет (нет наречного сочетания "по трёх/троих").

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: ***по трое детей.***

Это особый **дистрибутивный (распределительный)** падеж, и у него особые правила употребления грамматических форм.

§ 1380. Употребление числительных в составе сочетаний с предлогом по в так называемом **дистрибутивном (распределительном) значении** характеризуется двумя особенностями: 1) числительное в этом сочетании выступает или в форме дат. п. или в форме, совпадающей с формой им. п.; 2) при употреблении с предлогом по числительное всегда управляет существительным, а не согласуется с ним (сущ. всегда имеет форму Р.п ед. или мн. числа).http://rusgram.narod.ru/1366-1383.html

1) Количественные числ. два, три, четыре, девяносто, сто, двести, триста, четыреста и **собирательные числ. двое, трое, четверо** при предлоге по употребляются в форме, совпадающей с формой им. п.: дали по два карандаша, по две тетради, по три листа бумаги; по двое ножниц; по девяносто мест, по сто билетов, по триста рублей (сочетания по девяноста мест, по ста билетов являются устаревшими).

Также в Грамматике говорится о том, что при сочетании с одушевленными предметами используется форма им. (вин.) падежа: в каждом ряду ***по четыре человека***.

Интересна **история развития форм этого падежа**. В разное время, к примеру, были возможны три формы: по пяти рублям, по пяти рублей, по пять рублей. В настоящий момент первая форма не существует, вторая считается книжной и устаревающей, а треться форма нейтральной (из статьи: Дистрибутивная конструкция с предлогом по в русском языке 18-20 вв.).

Таким образом, существуют **два падежа с предлогом ПО**

1) обычный Д.п. с предлогом ПО:  Вдруг она вспомнила рассказ Дмитрия, как он стрелял **по двоим (солдатам)**, убегавшим от контрразведки, и как ранил одного в ногу.

2) дистрибутивный падеж с предлогом ПО:  Теперь Аня с Ниной сами матери, **по двое детей** у них.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вот что мне интересно. Я привожу полное грамматическое толкование этого вопроса и даже даю ссылку на исторический материал (как складывался распределительный падеж). **Но автору это неинтересно,** ему нужна одушевленность.

**А зачем она ему?** Откуда такой механистический подход к языку. Категория одушевленности существительных выражена не всегда, например: я вижу мальчика, девочку. Мы же не сомневаемся в одушевленности этой девочки, не требуем от нее Р.п. тоже.

**Форма "по троих" абсолютно неприемлема для нашего слуха,** только по трое/по троим. Эта форма не существует вовсе, но мы хотим, чтобы она существовала и выражала одушевленность, пусть даже вопреки здравому смыслу. К живому языку с его историческим развитием мы предъявляем эти придуманные нами механистические требования.